# How to sum integers with sign into a wider sum on IA32. 64-bit sum of 32-bit signed ints?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, sign-extension

I'm trying to sum a list of integers with sign on Assembly 32 but i have only got to sum integers without sign. Do you know some way to do it?

My program tries to sum integers and store in `resultado`, whose size is 64 bits, so to be able to do that I use two registers of 32 bits(EAX and EDX), and I check when the sum produces carry.

After of all that, I join EAX and EDX on resultado.

```
# sum.s     Sumar los elementos de una lista.
#           llamando a función, pasando argumentos mediante registros
# retorna:  código retorno 0, comprobar suma en %eax mediante gdb/ddd.
# as --32 -g sum.s -o sum.o
# ld -m elf_i386 sum.o -o sum

# DATA SECTION
.section .data
lista:
    .int 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295

longlista:
    .int (.-lista)/4
resultado:
    .quad -1


.section .text
_start: .global _start

    mov $lista, %ebx
    mov longlista, %ecx
    call suma
    mov %eax, resultado
    mov %edx, resultado+4

    mov $1, %eax
    mov $0, %ebx
    int $0x80


suma:
    push %esi
    mov $0, %eax
    mov $0, %edx
    mov $0, %esi

bucle:
    add (%ebx,%esi,4), %eax
    jc .L1

bucle1:
    inc %esi
    cmp %esi,%ecx
    jne bucle
    pop %esi
    ret

.L1:
    inc %edx
    jmp bucle1
```

This gives a 64-bit sum that treats the inputs as unsigned 32-bit, which isn't what I want.

Comment: It's the same for signed. Do you actually have a problem with this?

Comment: @Jester: Actually this code is zero-extending the 32-bit integers to 64-bit, not sign-extending.  (It's the same when the sum is the same width as the array elements, but that's not what the OP is doing here).

Comment: Ah, missed that.

Comment: @Antonio: it's simpler on x86-64: `movsxd (%rbx,%rsi,4), %rdx` / `add  %rdx, %rax` to sign extend.  As Sep says, on x86-32 the easiest way to sign-extend into a pair of registers is with `cdq` for extend `eax` into `edx:eax`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next code that uses 64-bit addition will give a correct sum for positive and negative numbers alike without any wraparound due to only using 32 bit registers.
The signed result can exceed the range [-2GB,+2GB-1].

```
suma:
    push %esi
    push %edi
    xor  %esi, %esi           ;Clear %edi:%esi
    xor  %edi, %edi
    sub  $1, %ecx             ;Start at last element in array
    jl   emptyArray
bucle:
    mov  (%ebx,%ecx,4), %eax  ;From signed 32-bit to signed 64-bit
    cdq
    add  %eax, %esi           ;Add signed 64-bit numbers
    adc  %edx, %edi
    dec  %ecx
    jge  bucle
emptyArray:
    mov  %esi, %eax           ;Move result from %edi:%esi to %edx:%eax
    mov  %edi, %edx
    pop  %edi
    pop  %esi
    ret
```

The order in which the additions are made is unimportant, and so the code starts with the last element working towards the first one.

Comment: If you're going to break out of the loop at zero, arrange it so you don't need a `test` instruction.  Fewer instructions *in the loop* is part of the point of looping towards zero.  e.g.  `dec %ecx` once before the loop, then `dec %ecx` / `jge` to treat the loop counter as signed, and have the loop run once when `ecx` = 0, stopping when it changes to `-1`.  (Or use a displacement in the addressing mode).  And BTW,  you don't need to save/restore `%ecx`; the OP seems to be using a somewhat normal calling convention where the usual registers are call-clobbered.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code implicitly zero-extends.  It's equivalent to `add (%ebx,%esi,4), %eax` / `adc $0, %edx`, but what you need to be adding to the upper half is 0 or `-1` depending on the sign of the low half.  (i.e. 32 copies of the sign bit; see Sep's answer).

---

32-bit x86 can do 64-bit integer math directly using SSE2/AVX2/AVX512 `paddq`.  (All 64-bit-capable CPUs support SSE2, so it's a reasonable baseline these days).

(Or MMX `paddq` if you care about Pentium-MMX through Pentium III / AMD Athlon-XP).

SSE4.1 makes sign-extending to 64-bit cheap.

```
pmovsxdq  (%ebx),  %xmm1     # load 2x 32-bit (Dword) elements, sign-extending into Qword elements
paddq     %xmm1, %xmm0
add       $8, %ebx

cmp / jb             # loop while %ebx is below an end-pointer.
# preferably unroll by 2 so there's less loop overhead,
# and so it can run at 2 vectors per clock on SnB and Ryzen.  (Multiple shuffle units and load ports)

# horizontal sum
pshufd    $0b11101110, %xmm0, %xmm1    # xmm1 = [ hi | hi ]
paddq     %xmm1, %xmm0                 # xmm0 = [ lo + hi | hi + hi=garbage ]

# extract to integer registers or do a 64-bit store to memory.
movq      %xmm0, (result)
```

I avoided an indexed addressing mode [so the load can stay micro-fused with `pmovsxdq` on Sandybridge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes).  Indexed is fine on Nehalem, Haswell or later, or on AMD.

---

Unfortunately there are **CPUs without SSE4.1** still in service.  In that case, you might want to just use scalar, but you can sign-extend manually.

There is no 64-bit arithmetic right shift, though.  (Only 64-bit element-size logical shifts).  But you can emulate `cdq` by copying and using a 32-bit shift to broadcast the sign bit, then unpack.

```
# prefer running this on aligned memory
# Most CPUs without SSE4.1 have slow movdqu

.loop:
    movdqa    (%ebx, %esi, 1), %xmm1      # 4x 32-bit elements
    movdqa    %xmm1, %xmm2
    psrad     $31, %xmm1                  # xmm1 = high halves (broadcast sign bit to all bits with an arithmetic shift)

    movdqa    %xmm2, %xmm3               # copy low halves again before destroying.
    punpckldq %xmm1, %xmm2                # interleave low 2 elements -> sign-extended 64-bit
    paddq     %xmm2, %xmm0

    punpckhdq %xmm1, %xmm3                # interleave hi  2 elements -> sign-extended 64-bit
    paddq     %xmm3, %xmm0

    add       $16, %esi
    jnc   .loop            # loop upward toward zero, with %ebx pointing to the end of the array.
    #end of one loop iteration, does 16 bytes
```

(Using two separate vector accumulators would likely be better than using two `paddq` into `xmm0`, to keep dependency chains shorter.)

This is more instructions, but it's doing twice as many elements per iteration.  It's still more instructions per `paddq`, but it's probably still better than scalar, especially on Intel CPUs before Broadwell where `adc` is 2 uops (because it has 3 inputs: 2 registers + EFLAGS).

It might be better to just copy %xmm1 twice before the first `psrad`.  On CPUs where `movdqa` has non-zero latency, I wanted to copy and then use the original to shorten the critical path so out-of-order execution has less latency to hide.

But this means the last `punpck` is reading the result of a chain of 2x `movdqa` register copies.  This might be worse on [CPUs with mov-elimination that doesn't work 100% of the time (Intel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all).  It might need a vector ALU to do the copy, because a chain of `mov` register copies is one of the cases where mov-elimination doesn't working perfectly.